# jQuery Autocomplete - How to CSS style the TextArea drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I am using a TextArea in my project along with jQuery autocomplete.

HTML CODE:

```
<textarea class='autoExpand' rows='5' data-min-rows='5' id='textarea'></textarea>
```

I have the javascript code to handle drop-down by using jQuery autocomplete. I can easily change the style of the TextArea itself:

```
    textarea{
    font-family: "Helvetica", Times, serif;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fffdb5;
    resize: none;
    }
```

However, I can't figure out how to CSS style the drop-down menu.
I need to be able to change the background of the drop-down as well as the colour of the text and selected item background.

To illustrate, this is what I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you add a piece of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

right mouse click on the drop down element and choosing "inspect element" (in firefox) helped me find it:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper { /* the selector */
    position: relative; /* pre-existing css */
    padding: 3px 1em 3px .4em; /* pre-existing css */
    color: red; /* new css */
    background: yellow; /* new css */
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely awesome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any idea how to style the selected item background?

Answer (score 1):

how to style the selected item background:

```
.ui-widget input.ui-autocomplete-input
{
    background: pink; /* new css */
}
```